# C++ How I can download html page via proxy using winsock2

Tags: c++, proxy, winsock2

How to download html page via proxy using winsock2

Thanks

Comment: this should be covers in 1) winsock documentation 2) HTTP documentation. Have you looked up either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different types of proxies use different types of communication protocols, so first you need to decide which type of proxies you want to support in the first place - the HTTP [`CONNECT`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01) verb, [SOCKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS), etc.  Implement that first, then once you have successfully established a socket connection with a target server through a proxy, then read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) for how to implement the HTTP protocol over that connection.

Comment: Maybe you can show me simple example for HTTP?

Comment: There are plenty of online examples of how to work with TCP/IP sockets, and how to implement HTTP with them. Search around.

Answer (score 0):

you dont even have to use c++. write a batch script to telnet the server you want to connect then use the command `get` . Then use `>>` operator to write it to a file

Comment: no, this is just a little part which my programm will do.